# How electricity consumption works

Tags: power-consumption

I am trying to understand how appliances can consume different amounts of electricity at different times. For example my laptop will consume different amounts of electricity depending on how much work it is doing. But how does it actually request more electricity?

Comment: Start understanding how three-position heater works before going to laptops.

Comment: Your laptop uses what it needs to.  It doesn't "Request" anything electrically.

Comment: That's not really how the national grid works. When you open a tap are you *requesting* more water? Not really, there is already water in the pipe and you're simply *allowing* more to flow. Same with electrical appliances, there's always electricity available, the load simply *allows* more to flow through it when it needs it. The load controls the flow, it is the master, it doesn't need permission, it just does it (much like how you don't have to ask permission from your water utility to have a shower, you just open the tap whenever you desire as needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVesIH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is actually a great analogy! Think of your computer as a machine that switches loads on and off all the time.